# Should I dup a question that looks and feels just like another question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Should I dup a question that looks and feels just like another question...
...with the exception that it is slightly less specific.

[potential dup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43286676/2336654)

[proposed original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43196550/2336654)

Comment: Will users who go to one be able to find an applicable answer at the other?

Comment: @KevinB yes, they will.